# Cannot get OpenCl to recognize AMD GPU (RX 480) after installing amdgpu-pro drivers

Tags: drivers, 20.04, gpu-driver, opencl, amdgpu-pro

After installing AMD's GPU drivers [here](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-20) (specifically "version 20.20 for Ubuntu 20.04"), OpenCl doesn't work.

To install the drivers I unarchived the tarball and ran `./amdgpu-pro-install -y --opencl=pal,legacy --headless` and `sudo usermod -a -G video $LOGNAME`.

The command `lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'` properly displays the installed GPU:
`01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] [1002:67df] (rev c7)`

But when I run `clinfo` I get an output of

```
Number of platforms                               2
  Platform Name                                   AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
  Platform Vendor                                 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 2.1 AMD-APP (3110.6)
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_icd cl_amd_event_callback cl_amd_offline_devices 
  Platform Host timer resolution                  1ns
  Platform Extensions function suffix             AMD

  Platform Name                                   Clover
  Platform Vendor                                 Mesa
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.1 Mesa 20.0.8
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_icd
  Platform Extensions function suffix             MESA

  Platform Name                                   AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Number of devices                                 0

  Platform Name                                   Clover
Number of devices                                 0

NULL platform behavior
  clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  No platform
  clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   No platform
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            No platform
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [other]              No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  No devices found in platform
```

After searching around I tried running `sudo apt-get install ocl-icd-opencl-dev`, but it was already installed.

Any help would be very appreciated. Please let me know if there is any information I could add that you think may be useful.

Comment: The `amdgpu-pro` driver might be incompletely installed. What's the output of `dpkg -l | grep amdgpu` ?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem trying to use OpenCl (for mining) via ssh (despite I installed amdgpu-pro using the --headless option). If you experience the issue via ssh try to log in directly after boot and start the specific process there as a workaround. If it does not work and you installed amdgpu-pro via ssh try to install it directly.

Answer (score 0):

### Attribution

First I tried to install the amdgpu software for the particular videocard, but I was not able to get that working successfully. Furthermore, the `./amdgpu-install` and `amdgpu-pro-install` scripts froze the terminal for a significant amount of time. Hence, after some trial and error I followed the steps from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efKjfBkjPlM), which explains the/a more detailed- process suggested in the answer by TurboSlayer in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1336913/opencl-not-working-with-rx-6700-xt). I verified the instructions work by  inspecting the output of both `clinfo` and `rocminfo` and observing the respective cards are indeed recognized in the output of both of these commands.

### Code

```
# Source of commands: https://rocmdocs.amd.com/en/latest/Installation_Guide/Installation-Guide.html

yes | sudo apt update
yes | sudo apt dist-upgrade
yes | sudo apt install libnuma-dev
yes | sudo apt install wget gnupg2
wget -q -O - https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/rocm.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
echo 'deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/debian/ ubuntu main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rocm.list
yes | sudo apt update
sudo reboot

# Open a terminal after reboot and run:
yes | sudo apt install rocm-dkms
sudo usermod -aG video $LOGNAME
sudo usermod -aG render $LOGNAME
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/opt/rocm/bin:/opt/rocm/profiler/bin:/opt/rocm/opencl/bin' | sudo tee -a /etc/profile.d/rocm.sh


# Wait till everything is installed and reboot again
sudo reboot

# Verify the videocards are recognized with:
clinfo
rocminfo
```

Next, one wants to ensure that OpenCL actually finds those cards. By default OpenCL looks into its own directory for the `amdocl64_40000.icd` (which is just some file it apparently needs, I thought it was card-dependent due to the 40000 code but it does not look like that). However that file is actually located in the `rocm` folder when using this procedure so change the path of that `amdocl64_40000.icd` file with:

```
sudo nano /etc/OpenCL/vendors/amdocl64_40000.icd
```

and change:

```
libamdocl64.so
```

to:

```
/opt/rocm/opencl/lib/libamdocl64.so
```

Now you shouldn't get the `Failed to list OpenCL platforms` error anymore. [Source for this last step](https://github.com/todxx/teamredminer/issues/244).

### Note

The script was ran on a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 installation. The above instructions did not work after uninstalling the `amdgpu-install` nor `amdgpu-pro-install` files. I guess something which also was used by `rocm` was corrupted during that `amdgpu-install` process, which I guess did not happen at the fresh Ubuntu 20.04 installation.